# I do not understand the role of "respectively" in this

Tags: meaning-in-context

> https://www.rtu.lv/en/science/research-platforms/energy-and-environment

The first paragraph is the article is this:

> Nowadays life and economic activity are not imaginable without
>   electricity, thermal energy, and transport fuel, and, respectively,
>   power supply.

Meaning of respectively:
adverb

1.
in precisely the order given; sequentially.

2.
(of two or more things, with reference to two or more things previously mentioned) referring or applying to in a parallel or sequential way:
Joe and Bob escorted Betty and Alice, respectively.

Considering the first meaning of respectively , are we saying power supply comes after electricity , thermal energy and transport fuel?

The second meaning does not seem to apply , but I'm not sure.

Can somebody please help me out?

Comment: The use of *respectively* here is unclear to me, and I think it's unlikely that a native speaker would use the word this way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the (Latvian) source contains many other errors and shortcomings in addition to the specific erroneous usage cited here. It's not a text that's meaningfully worth studying to help learn English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/respectively) and the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/respectively), **respectively** has only one meaning:

> Separately or individually and in the order already mentioned (used when enumerating two or more items or facts that refer back to a previous statement)

Here is an example to show how it should be used:

> We now have before us a skeletal account of the way in which sexism and racism construe women and blacks, respectively.

In this sentence, **respectively** is an adverb that modifies **construes**: it associates sexism with women and racism with blacks. Note that there is the same number of items in the first and second lists.

In the sentence that you quoted, **respectively** is being used incorrectly, as:

1. there is no verb for it to modify
2. there are three items in the list before it and only one item in the list following it.
3. Resepectively should be used after the second list, not before it.